# Is onLoadFinished() asynchronous (background thread)?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I am currently looking at using a loader manager to populate my expandablelistview in a drawerlayout.  I cannot find anywhere in the documentation if the callback function onLoadFinished() is running on the UI thread or on a background thread.  Is it on a background thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have called `init()` from the UI thread, `onLoadFinished()` will definitely be called on the UI thread. In cases when you call from background for example an `AsyncTaskLoader` the thread that will be notified about the outcome will be the thread from where you init loader.

...But you still can do the following:

```
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> arg0, String arg1) {
        Runnable populate = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //your code
            }

        };
        if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
            //on Ui thread
            populate.run();
        }else{
            this.runOnUiThread(populate); //or use handler to run the runnable
        }

    }
```

:)

Comment: When I added the check to see if the callback is in MainThread this is what I am seem to getting.. "Init not in Main thread","Finished in Main Thread". <p> Please note that I had called the Loader from a separate thread. Does this mean no matter how you call init loader, your onLoadFinished gets called in UI thread ?

Answer (score 2):

[http://www.amazon.com/Android-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides/dp/0321804333](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321804333), pg. 566.

"The onFinishedLoad() method will be called on the main thread once the data has been loaded in the background."

Answer (score 0):

Add code below will solve the prob that calling getView() in onLoadFinished() returns NullPointerException

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getSupportLoaderManager().destroyLoader(LOADER_ID);
}
```